# Al intentar inciar la segunda ventan parpadea y se cierra

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from Ventana_principal import VentanaPrincipal

from Ventana_nueva_op import VentanaNuevaOperacion

class Main():
   
    def ventanaNuevaOperacion(self):
        interfazNuevaOperacion = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = VentanaNuevaOperacion()
        ui.setupUi(interfazNuevaOperacion)
        interfazNuevaOperacion.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    ejecutar = Main()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Crea la aplicacion
    interfazPrincipal = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()  # Crea la ventana
    ui = VentanaPrincipal()  # Accede al objeto que es toda la interfaz
    ui.setupUi(interfazPrincipal)  # Carga la configuracion al padre mainwindow
    interfazPrincipal.showMaximized()
    interfazPrincipal.show()  # Muestra la ventana
    ui.actionNueva_operacion.triggered.connect(ejecutar.ventanaNuevaOperacion)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Añadir que si ejecuto esta misma lógica en el archivo de `ventanaprincipal` me lo carga perfectamente, pero si lo hago así parpadea la ventana y luego desaparece, la segunda ventana funciona perfectamente ejecutándola de manera independiente

Comment: Esto ocurre porque no mantienes una referencia y por tanto el colector de basura de python la elimina. simplemente guarda un puntero hacia la nueva ventana desde la ventana principal o la `app`.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero soy muy novato en esto podrias ponerme un ejemplo pequeño para entender la logica de echo es una sorpresa que use punteros python par mi :) ni lo sabia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto ocurre porque no mantienes una referencia y por tanto el colector de basura de python la elimina. simplemente guarda un puntero hacia la nueva ventana desde la ventana principal o la `app`

**Explicación:**
Tu código está ejecutando solamente `app` en bucle, lo que quiere decir que cualquier cosa que se cree y no esté "vinculada" a algo relacionado con app va a desaparecer porque va a ser recolectado como basura. Dejame ponerte un ejemplo:

```
def ejemplo():
  a = 1
  b = 1
  c = a + b
  return c
```

Si ese código se lanza en python, qué crees que ocurriría con `a` y `b`? Despues de ejecutarse la función, Python efectivamente los elimina de la memoria, al no ser necesarios nunca más; los recolecta como basura porque el código ya se ha ejecutado y ha cumplido su función.

Lo que te ocurre con tu ventana nueva es similar, el código se ejecuta y entonces python dice "ah, ya se ha ejecutado, lo recolecto como basura". Esto ocurre porque no está vinculado a algo que sí se está ejecutando continuamente (una `app` es básicamente un bucle infinito, por eso nunca se cierra hasta que el usuario decida cerrarla manualmente. Esa es la diferencia entre una app/programa y un script).

La solución sería tan simple como hacer que la ventana nueva sea parte de la app o algun elemento de ello. Algunos ejemplos válidos serían:

**Ejemplo 1:**
Al añadirlo como parametro de app, no debería desaparecer.

```
app.interfazNuevaOperacion = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
```

**Ejemplo 2:**
Para no alterar mucho tu código, yo haría esto:

```
def ventanaNuevaOperacion(self, app):
    interfazNuevaOperacion = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = VentanaNuevaOperacion()
    ui.setupUi(interfazNuevaOperacion)
    # Añade una referencia a algo que se esté ejecutando, en este caso a app
    app.ventanasactivas.append(interfazNuevaOperacion)  
    interfazNuevaOperacion.show()
```

Y llamaríamos al código así:

```
# aquí le pasamos el parametro app a la función que crea la ventana
ui.actionNueva_operacion.triggered.connect(lambda: ejecutar.ventanaNuevaOperacion(app))
```

Para que ese código funciona, recomendaría que añadas de antemano una lista vacía como parametro de app, para manejar las ventanas:

```
app.ventanasactivas = []
```

Este es un ejemplo muy tonto, pero de esa manera, tu código no se cerrara.

**Finalmente:**
Un consejo es que te crees tu propio Administrador de ventanas que Añada y Elimine ventanas de la lista/app de manera razonable.

Y como off-topic, sugeriría que utilizes Pyside2 en lugar de Pyqt5, son esencialmente lo mismo pero [Pyside2](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/) tiene soporte oficial de Qt y licencias algo más permisivas.

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora lo entendi por completo y para alguien que tenga un problema similar funciona perfectamente su ejemplo en cuanto a pyside2 lo estudiare (como habia mas tutoriales de pyqt5... :)) Gracias otra vez                          simplificando aun mas cuando pones en el codigo de arriba interfazNuevaOperacion = QtWidgets.QMainWindow(interfazPrincipal) tambien lo saca

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas entendido. Si esta ha sido una respuesta valida, acuerdate de aceptarla como válida, usando los controles a la izquierda de la respuesta. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow.